# add new encodings for file saving in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I need to change settings in Visual studio 2015 to save files in 1251 encodin, howeever I don't have such option in encoding selection in File->Advanced Save Options... How could I add new encoding there? 
On the first picture Advanced Save Options... settings at my teammate, and on the second list of encodings I can select.

[image: my friend settings]

[image: my list of options]

Comment: Very likely your file contains characters not in the 1251 character set. When you try with an empty file, what options do you get?

Comment: the same. We checked on the same file and he has a lot of options and I have only this three

Comment: Are you running a different localized version of Windows?

Comment: the same version